# Admob implementation in developed app in Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, admob, android-webview

I developed a Android app successfully, later I want to implement admob banner and interstitial.  I wasted​ my many sleeps with many errors.
here is sorce code, plzz help me someone plzzzz. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzIEX5W66bPAMXlCOUhYVHNBWHM/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: tell me your error, what you not able to resolve ?

Comment: Abhishek bhai, many problems have solved. Last problem is-- there is a space of banner is displaying of bottom of the layout but that is blank, none ads is displaying.plzzzz help

Comment: @AbhishekAryan Abhishek bhai, many problems have solved. Last problem is-- there is a space of banner is displaying of bottom of the layout but that is blank, none ads is displaying.plzzzz help

Comment: @AbhishekAryan here is Mainactivity.java  https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzIEX5W66bPAMkd5T0dvM1YzVnc

Comment: @AbhishekAryan here is activity_main.xml https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzIEX5W66bPASGJsZThmTkl6WTA/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @AbhishekAryan Sir!  I'm not a technical guy , I'm curious learner. plz  correct my codes. I'll be thankful for life. :)

Comment: Have you ad_unit id, app_id and one google-services.json file ? These there files required to integrate AdMob ad with firebase.

Answer (score 1):

First remove all your admob logic from your app, then add project in firebase [console](https://console.firebase.google.com) then follow this [guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/quick-start) carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Test your App Ad with TestDevice, check placement :

```
AdRequest.Builder adRequestBuilder = new AdRequest.Builder();
adRequestBuilder.addTestDevice(XXXXXXXXX);
topView.loadAd(adRequestBuilder.build());
```

If you're checking with live ad :

> "It could be that you have only recently created a new Ad Unit ID and
>   requesting for live ads. It could take a few hours for ads to start
>   getting served if that is that case. If you are receiving test ads
>   then your implementation is fine. Just wait a few hours and see if you
>   are able to receive live ads then. If not, can send us your Ad Unit ID
>   for us to look into."

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/android/fBe3YL3ffpo

so wait for a few hours.